# Why should I use __DIR__ when creating an SQLite database with PDO?

Tags: php, database, sqlite, pdo

I am very junior working with PHP, and until now, I have been working with mysqli. I have been told to learn PHP in general, so, I found a tutorial for doing CRUD using SQLite PDO.

I literally just started it with the first video, and I am confused already...
I have done research on internet and php documentation, but I can't find the answer I am looking for.

```
$db = new PDO("sqlite:".__DIR__."/the_database.db");
```

This is the line to create the database; my question:

Does the database needs to be in the root directory of my project? I am finding so many different options on internet..... almost all of them the database doesn't even finish with .db but with .sqlite .... but I hope this part will be explained later on the tutorial.

My big question is, why am I adding `".__DIR.__"`, is it because it HAS TO BE on the root folder? Or could I just place it as `$db = new PDO("sqlite:"the_database.db");` ? I have been trying to answer the question myself, trying to find how to "SHOW DATABASES" or something like that but this SQLite seems so complex....

Thank you

Comment: `__DIR__` is not the root directory. It's the directory of the file where you call it. Check [Magic Constants](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) for further details.

Comment: But, the file gets created with that line, right? I understood that.... and if I do echo (__DIR__); it displays my project's root folder. (exactly /ltd/www/sites/motors06/root/my_tracker, as I work on the server).

So, what do you mean it is the directory of the file where I call it?

Thank you :)

Comment: He means the when your script is in the root folder, then `__DIR__` displays the root folder.

Comment: It displays `/ltd/www/sites/motors06/root/my_tracker` because the *.php file is saved at `/ltd/www/sites/motors06/root/my_tracker`. If you save the file at `/somewhere/else` it'll display `/somewhere/else`. And please note we're talking about the specific file as you see it in your text editor, not the top level script where you might be doing a `require` of the previous file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you don't have to use PDO with SQLite. You can use it with mysql if you wish. And I am sure that there are a lot of videos that are using mysql as well. Though I am strongly convinced that all video tutorials are crap that will make you not a programmer but something opposite.

Now back to SQLite. So your question boils down to the `__DIR__` constant which simply denotes the directory where lies the script where it written.

You see, SQLite database is simply a *file.* So it can have whatever name or extension, and be placed in any directory of your choice. The only problem with is *the access* to a newly created database. Imagine there are two php scripts on your site, one is

```
/index.php
```

and another is

```
/account/register.php
```

both working with a database.

If you address an SQLite database file as just "sqlite:the_database.db", then you'll end up with TWO databases - one in the root folder and one in the account folder. This is why you have to always prefix the filename with the **absolute path**. And `__DIR__` constant is one of the ways to do so. If have a **single** file where `$db = new PDO` is called, then it's ok to use this constant

Comment: ok.... it seems a bit clearer now, but at the same time I am super lost. Do you know anywhere where I can understand how SQLite works in a very basic way? As I said I have read it on php documentation and I do not understand, in fact.... I don't use it very much because all php explained there I feel it complicated :s

Comment: Well, basically sqlite works just like any other SQL database. You don't actually know how it works. Just use it. In a very basic way it's just a file, where your data is stored and you are using SQL to query that data.